# Is there a way to merge or combine two arrays received from Laravel Query?

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to achieve a combined array from the query result of two or more queries. The solution what I have tried so far is given below.

Created one variable `$total_records` and iterated over it again in a `foreach` loop to get the second set of data output. Now I want to merge output#2 into output#1 received at the first place in `total_records`

There is a query#1:

```
$total_records = RatioStatistics::where('type', '=', 'group')
->whereBetween('date', [$modified_start_date, $modified_end_date])
->join('cart_abondon_group', 'statistics.ref_id', '=', 'cart_abondon_group.id')
->select('statistics.*', 'cart_abondon_group.name')
->orderBy('statistics.ref_id', 'ASC')
->orderBy('statistics.date', 'ASC')
->get();
```

Output#1:

```
[{
    "id": 324985,
    "ref_id": 1,
    "date": "2019-01-02T00:00:13+00:00",
    "total": 434,
    "available": 164,
    "rented": 270,
    "unusable": 0
}, 
{
    "id": 325602,
    "ref_id": 1,
    "date": "2019-01-03T00:00:16+00:00",
    "total": 427,
    "available": 176,
    "rented": 251,
    "unusable": 0
}]
```

There is another query#2:

```
foreach ($total_records as $record) {
    $data = [
        'total_number_of_cart_abondon_of_the_day' => Cart::where('created_at', 'like', $record['date']->format('Y-m-d') . '%')
        ->whereNotIn('status_id', [11])
        ->whereHas('product', function ($q) use ($record) {
            $q->where('group_id', $record['ref_id']);
        })
        ->count(),
        'total_number_of_cart_abondon_per_day_per_warehouse_user' => Cart::where('created_at', 'like', $record['date']->format('Y-m-d') . '%')
        ->where('warehouse_user', 1)
        ->whereNotIn('status_id', [11])
        ->whereHas('product', function ($q) use ($record) {
            $q->where('group_id', $record['ref_id']);
        })
        ->count()
    ];

    $new_stats[] = $data;
}
```

Output 2:

```
"0": {
    "total_number_of_cart_abondon_of_the_day": 27,
    "total_number_of_cart_abondon_per_day_per_warehouse_user": 0
}, 
"1": {
    "total_number_of_cart_abondon_of_the_day": 30,
    "total_number_of_cart_abondon_per_day_per_warehouse_user": 0
}
```

Requested Output:

1. Either I will have to make a solution like that so that we can query everything through the first query itself without running the second query.
2. Or make the second query more optimised so that output#2 can be clubbed into output#1

Correct Desired Output:

```
[{
    "id": 324985,
    "ref_id": 1,
    "date": "2019-01-02T00:00:13+00:00",
    "total": 434,
    "available": 164,
    "rented": 270,
    "unusable": 0,
    "total_number_of_cart_abondon_of_the_day": 27,
    "total_number_of_cart_abondon_per_day_per_warehouse_user": 0
}, {
    "id": 325602,
    "ref_id": 1,
    "date": "2019-01-03T00:00:16+00:00",
    "total": 427,
    "available": 176,
    "rented": 251,
    "unusable": 0,
    "total_number_of_cart_abondon_of_the_day": 30,
    "total_number_of_cart_abondon_per_day_per_warehouse_user": 0
}]
```

Comment: What kind of relationship exists between `RadioStatistics` (statistics table) and `Cart` (cart_abondon_group table) models?

Comment: @IGP There is no relation between ```RadioStatistics``` and ```Cart``` table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call

```php
foreach ($total_records as $record) {
    $data = [
        'total_number_of_cart_abondon_of_the_day' => Cart::where...,
        'total_number_of_cart_abondon_per_day_per_warehouse_user' => Cart::where...
    ]
}
```

You're making an extra **2 sql queries per record.**

Assuming `RadioStatistics` is `statistics` table's model and `Cart` is `cart_abondon_group` table's model, this can be fixed as follows:

1. Make a relationship method in `RadioStatistics` model

```php
# statistics has a foreign key (ref_id) that references cart_abondon_group's primary key (id)
public function carts()
{
    return this->belongsTo(Cart::class, 'ref_id', 'id'); // Assuming Cart is cart_abondon_group's model
}
```

2. Remake query 1 to so it takes advantage of that:

```php
$total_records = RatioStatistics::where('type', '=', 'group')
->whereBetween('date', [$modified_start_date, $modified_end_date])
->join('cart_abondon_group', 'statistics.ref_id', '=', 'cart_abondon_group.id')
// WithCount must be before select or it won't be added to the results
->withCount([
    'carts as total_number_of_cart_abondon_of_the_day' => function ($carts) {
        $carts->whereRaw("cart_abondon_group.created_at like concat(date_format('statistics.date', '%d-%m-%Y'), '%')")
        ->whereNotIn('status_id', [11])
        ->whereHas('product', function ($q) use ($record) {
            $q->whereRaw('group_id = statistics.id');
        });
    },
    'carts as total_number_of_cart_abondon_per_day_per_warehouse_user' => function ($carts) {
        $carts->whereRaw("cart_abondon_group.created_at like concat(date_format('statistics.date', '%d-%m-%Y'), '%')")
        ->where('warehouse_user', 1)
        ->whereNotIn('status_id', [11])
        ->whereHas('product', function ($q) use ($record) {
            $q->whereRaw('group_id = statistics.id');
        });
    }
])
->select('statistics.*', 'cart_abondon_group.name')
->orderBy('statistics.ref_id', 'ASC')
->orderBy('statistics.date', 'ASC')
->get();
```

The tricky part is the date. I don't really get why your schema has two different formats.

Comment: Thanks IGP. Thanks a ton. For the date part, I am quite helpless, even I don't know why 2 kinda date formats are used.